# Can "however" and "but" be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage, comparison

Can they be used interchangeably? If not, in which situations should I use the former and the latter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When they're interchangeable...**

The following sentences are typical uses of "but/however" (note the different punctuation, hat tip:@snailboat):

> I wanted to go to the store, **but** I didn't have enough time.
>   I wanted to go to the store; **however**, I didn't have enough time.

In these sentences, the two words are essentially interchangeable. The version with "but" is probably a little more informal.

**When they're not...**

There are other uses of the two words, however, where they are not interchangeable. Here are a few examples:

*Examples where you can use only "but"...*

> - I liked all **but** one of the songs on that album. [used as a preposition to mean "except"]
> - I am **but** your humble servant. [used as an adverb to mean "only"]
> - I don't want to hear any ifs, ands, or **buts**. [used as a noun as part of an idiom]

*Examples where you can use only "however"...*

> - I'll pay for it **however** I can. [used as an adverb to mean "in whatever way"]
> - There are other uses of the two words, **however**, where they are not interchangeable. [used as an aside]

Comment: *However* isn't a coordinator in standard English.  "I wanted to go to the store, however I didn't have enough time" is probably not kosher.

Comment: Are you saying you'd punctuate the sentence differently? The sentence sounds fine to my ear.

Comment: Sure.  It's fine as two sentences: "I wanted to go to the store.  However, I didn't have enough time."

Comment: Or: "I wanted to go to the store; however, I didn't have enough time."

Comment: Sure, that's fine too.